# ActiveAdmin form: multiple nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, nested-forms

I have a structure `User-> Profile-> Image` and want to use one form for editing and recording in `ActiveAdmin`.
I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`in models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy;
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image, dependent: :destroy;
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image,:reject_if => proc { |attributes| !attributes['img'].present? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :img
  validates_attachment_content_type :img, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

And such `permit_params` in `ActiveAdmin.register User`:

```
  permit_params do   
    permitted=[:id,:login, :email, :admin, :password, :password_confirmation, :ip_address];
    permitted.append(profile_attributes:[:name,:second_name,:middle_name,:img,:mobile_phone,:country, :city,:region, image_attributes:[:img]]);
    permitted
  end
```

Finally, the code itself forms

```
form do |f| 
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :login
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end 
     f.inputs "Profile", for:  [:profile, f.object.profile || f.object.build_profile] do |pf|
      pf.input :name
      pf.input :second_name
      pf.input :middle_name
      pf.input :mobile_phone, :as => :phone
      pf.input :country,  selected: "RU"
      pf.input :city
      pf.input :region
      pf.inputs "Avatar", for:[:image, pf.object.image || pf.object.build_image] do |fpf|
        fpf.input :img, :as => :file
      end 
    end 
    f.inputs "User Perference" do
      f.input :admin, type: :boolean
    end 
    f.actions    
  end
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work: the form is correctly displayed with `Profile` and work, but the form is not visible to the `Image`[image]. How can I fix this?

Comment: why Profile `belongs_to :image` and not the other way around?

Comment: To store a `FK ` in `profiles`  table, and not as `images`.  Image model will later be use with different models, it should not be due to other.

Comment: I had already tried something similar with no success. :( I suggest you to bind the Image model to User.

Comment: I got to `SimpleForm` in `update`-action, but `ActiveAdmin` still continues to ignore the multiple nested forms.

Comment: Maybe it is too late, but you can find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563922/multilevel-nested-form-not-showing-in-active-admin

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not found the right solution for this problem, and it is still relevant (I'm not going to close this question, just in case someday it will answer).

But I modeled the behavior close to the desired one.

So, to the `User` model I added `Avatar`-interface for the respective object.

```
  def avatar
    if self.profile && self.profile.image
      self.profile.image.img  
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def avatar=(arg)
    unless self.profile.image
      self.profile.create_image(img:arg)
    else
      self.profile.image.update_attributes(img:arg)
    end
    self.profile.image
  end

  def avatar?
    if self.profile && self.profile.image
      !self.profile.image.img.nil?
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

In ActiveAdmin added to the avatar permit_params for User.

```
 permit_params ..., :avatar
```

Finally, in the form of added file fields:

```
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      #Fields for User
    end
     f.inputs "profile", for:  [:profile, f.object.profile || f.object.build_profile] do |pf|
       #Fields for profile
    end
    f.inputs "Avatar" do
      f.input :avatar, as: :file
    end
    f.actions                                        
  end
```

It is worth noting that if you have observed abnormal behavior when the form is submitted, with empty values, then you should pay attention to the parameters for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, in particular `update_only` and `reject_if`.

I'm still waiting for the normal solution for multiple nested forms in ActiveAdmin