# Multilevel Nested form not showing in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, nested-forms

I'm trying to Implement a multilevel Nested form.

These are my models

workout.rb

```
has_many :workout_weeks
accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_weeks
```

workout_week.rb

```
belongs_to :workout
has_many :workout_days
accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_days
```

workout_day.rb

```
belongs_to :workout_week
```

and my workout edit part in active admin is like

```
form do |f|
  inputs 'Workout Details' do
    f.input :workout_name
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :workout_weeks, heading: 'Workout Week', allow_destroy: true do |ww|
        ww.input :week_workout_name
        ww.inputs do
          ww.has_many :workout_days, heading: 'Workout Days', allow_destroy: true do |wd|
            wd.input :day_workout_name
          end
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Did I miss anything here, 
The form for edit field is not available in the view. Its not generated.
My view is like this now.

[image: Screenshot of workout form]

Why is my workout_day form not getting rendered here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
form do |f|
  inputs 'Workout Details' do
    f.input :workout_name
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :workout_weeks, heading: 'Workout Week', allow_destroy: true do |ww|
        ww.input :week_workout_name
        ww.has_many :workout_days, heading: 'Workout Days', allow_destroy: true do |wd|
          wd.input :day_workout_name
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

you can't put a `inputs` in a `inputs`